# Как настроить отбражение всех значений по оси X и плотность меток меньше 100%?

Tags: powerbi

Имеется график с плотностью меток 22%.
[image: график]
Как настроить отображение всех меток по оси X?
Если для оси выбрать тип "Категориальный", то настройка с плотностью меток пропадает.
Кроме того, как настроить угол наклона для подписей на оси X?